# Bazel Clang cross platform

Tags: bazel

---

I'm trying to get bazel to use clang as the compiler on both Windows and Linux. (Debian 10 if that matters)
On Windows I managed to get it working by adding a windows-clang platform and registering the toolchain as described [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html#build-c-with-clang).
Is there a similarly easy way to get switch to using clang on Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dug around a but and as far as I can tell, you have two (or three options):

1. You can [configure](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html) your won `cc_toolchain`. This may be arguably the "correct" solution.
2. You can try to tweak `cc_configure()` from [`@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_configure.bzl`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/cc_configure.bzl) and use it in your `WORKSPACE`. But that is both challenging and not necessarily pretty.

Neither of the two ways are likely to qualify as "easy". For that, the quickest would appear to be:

3. Automagic toolchain resolution considers environmental variable `CC` (only, not `CXX`) and if set its value is used for toolchain configuration. Hence, for instance this would do:

   ```
   CC=/usr/bin/clang bazel build //:some_tgt
   ```

I hope I haven't missed anything, but I have not spotted a way to choose compiler through [`platform`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/platform.html#platform)s (without having your own toolchain definition in place) as of today.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of, but I was hoping I missed something. I used to use crosstool but that has been deorecated.